# Is it possible to set up a first time splash screen?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

Is it possible to use a certain image for a loading screen when it's the first time the app is ever opened, and then after that use a different image for the loading for all visits after that?

Basically I'm creating about 10 files (not large in size) when the app is first launched and I wanted to display a message to the user so they don't think that the app normally takes more than a second to load up. I know I can display a popup on the home screen, but I have an animation that fires when you go to the home screen and also I need those files created before the user arrives there. Any ideas? Or maybe a different view point that I didn't mention?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't change the splash screen.  Maybe you should rethink how your initial 10 files are created, and take Paul's suggestion of showing a popup control while you do the work, or better yet, offloading it into the background?  I guess it depends if your created files are required for something in the UI

--edit--

Actually, the more I think about it, the more I favour a background thread doing the work while you have a popup control displayed to the user.  It would allow you to give the user feedback on what is actually going on.  If your popup says something like "Preparing this application for its first run...", and then shows a progress bar that updates when each file is created, the user is getting feedback on exactly *why* the app is taking so long to load the first time.  Otherwise they may think "This app is very slow, I wonder if there is a better one out there"

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what you were thinking when you said "Popup", but you could create a full screen `Popup` [(in the System.Windows.Controls.Primitive sense of Popup)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.popup%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) that completely covers your main UI so that the user can't see it.

Your temporary loading UI would be defined as a `UserControl` described in XAML/C# in the same way as a normal `PhoneApplicationPage`.

When your files are ready and you close the popup you should send a message to the View (i.e. `.xaml.cs`) of your main page that will cause the animation to be replayed with all contents visible.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have tried this, it's just that I was wondering if we could change the splash screen.